# Reply address appending sender domain

Tags: marketing-cloud

We're having an issue right now with certain users replying to emails (the reply does go through) but their sender email address has changed and appended the send domain to it.

It would normally look like: useremail@gmail.com
But it's been changed to: useremail.gmail.com@senderdomain.com

This causes issues when someone tries to respond back to that reply, as it will no longer go back to the user (because the email address does not exist on our domain). Any idea why this might be happening? Is this an issue with our reply mail management?

Comment: Did you change anything in Reply Mail Management?

Comment: @garek007 nope, it's an automated email that's been running with the same sender profile for at least a year, with no changes to RMM

Answer (score 0):

Check the Reply Mail Management settings on the business unit and also the Custom Reply Mail Management settings on the Sender Profile. Also if you have a parent account using RMM rules, you’ll need to see if those are applying anything to child accounts.